# Android app. with its own keyboard?

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

Is it possible to make an Android app. that defines its own keyboard and switches to it when the app. is running? But reverts to the user's default keyboard when he / she switches back to a different app?

I understand the virtues of decoupling apps. from input devices, but when you want quite a close connection (eg. keys on the keyboard that only make sense in a particular app.) can you couple them more tightly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have clearly understood your question...

In the Linux an Android input event framework, different keylayouts for different devices in the directory `/system/usr/keylayout` are used to mapped the key values from kernel to userspace app.

If the Android app has the permission to change the system file, some key maps can be changed or be disable. But these key maps files are loaded when system booting...

So, in conclusion, personally I think it's really really hard to implement this feature in Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Just found http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm which seems a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It most certainly is. But in order to do that the user must **explicitly** accept and enable the IME packed with your app as an input method. The problem is that when you leave your application the IME must be **explicitly** switched back to the default IME. [Quoting](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html):

> After installing the desired IMEs, a user can select which one to use
>   from the system settings, and use it **across the entire system**; only
>   one IME may be enabled at a time.

So to recap you cannot change keyboards automatically when your user enters your app **without** explicit user interaction.

I am going to suggest what I think might be a work-around:

Any View that is Editable will [trigger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType(int)) the `IME`, whether that is a keyboard or anything else, what you are going to do is create custom `View`s that when they receive focus you animate another view of your own that will come up and act as be your keyboard.